# How do I apply removeEventListener on an (scoped) addEventListener in a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

In a global scope you can remove an eventListener. The next code works and is to show the desired behavior; The first button triggers an altert and the second doesn't.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const button1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
  const button2 = document.getElementById('button-2');
  
  button1.addEventListener('click', helloAlert);
  
  button2.addEventListener('click', helloAlert);
  button2.removeEventListener('click', helloAlert);
});

function helloAlert(){
  window.alert('hello');
};
```

```html
<button id='button-1'>addEventListener</button>
<button id='button-2'>addEventListener & removeEventListener</button>
```

In an OOP situation I would end up in a situation like this.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let button1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
  let messenger1 = new Messenger( button1, 'hello 1' );
  messenger1.addHelloAlert();
  
  let button2 = document.getElementById('button-2');
  let messenger2 = new Messenger( button2, 'hello-2' );
  messenger2.addHelloAlert();
  messenger2.removeHelloAlert();
});

class Messenger{

  constructor( button, message ){
    this.button = button;
    this.text = message;
  }
  
  addHelloAlert(){
    this.button.addEventListener('click', this.giveMessage.bind(this));
  }
  
  removeHelloAlert(){
    // this is where I get stuck because 
    // I cannot reference to the relevant function 
    // to remove the eventListener
    this.button.removeEventListener('click', this.giveMessage );
  }
  
  giveMessage(){
    window.alert( this.text );
  };
}
```

```html
<button id='button-1'>addEventListener</button>
<button id='button-2'>addEventListener & removeEventListener</button>
```

As you can see the eventListener is not removed by the OOP code, because the function isn't selected.

Anyone with ideas how to solve this in **regular JavaScript** and OOP?

Comment: Please note -> `this.giveMessage.bind(this)` is not equal to `this.giveMessage`, when adding removing events they have to be identical.  Also `this.giveMessage.bind(this)` is not equal to `this.giveMessage.bind(this)` either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `bind` the `this.giveMessage` handler in the *constructor*, that way it can be added and removed at will later without further binding, as often seen in frameworks like React when handlers are involved:

```js
class Messenger {
  constructor(button, message) {
    this.button = button;
    this.text = message;
    this.giveMessage = this.giveMessage.bind(this);
  }

  addHelloAlert() {
    this.button.addEventListener('click', this.giveMessage);
  }

  removeHelloAlert() {
    this.button.removeEventListener('click', this.giveMessage);
  }

  giveMessage() {
    console.log(this.text);
  };
}

let button1 = document.getElementById('button-1');
let messenger1 = new Messenger(button1, 'hello 1');
messenger1.addHelloAlert();

let button2 = document.getElementById('button-2');
let messenger2 = new Messenger(button2, 'hello-2');
messenger2.addHelloAlert();
messenger2.removeHelloAlert();
```

```html
<button id='button-1'>addEventListener</button>
<button id='button-2'>addEventListener & removeEventListener</button>
```

If you don't want to attach the bound listener to the *instance* for some reason (like encapsulation / privacy), another option would be to assign to an outer scoped `Map`.

Comment: Great, that works! I don't fully understand why it works however. If anyone happens to know a good article about handler binding in constructors that would be a good addition/comment on this answer.

Comment: The `bind`ing action ensures that calls of `giveMessage` have `this` refer to the instance. Because the instance is essentially created in the constructor, it makes sense to bind in the constructor too, so that further references to `this.giveMessage` will refer to the bound function (and can be added and removed as desired)

Comment: If it seems confusing to use the same property name, you could accomplish the same thing by referencing a *different* name, eg `this.boundGiveMessage = this.giveMessage.bind(this)`. In that code, the `this.giveMessage` part refers to the method on the *prototype*, while the `this.boundGiveMessage` assigns to a property *directly on the instance*.

Comment: To add to @CertainPerfomance, remember in Javascript methods don't have an implicit `this`, basically what `bind` does is wrap the function inside another, that will then kind of do a `call` for you.  IOW:  Javascript implicitly only carries `this` if you call the function with a preceding `.`,..  eg. `obj.func()` works because `obj` get passed as `this` for `func`..   `var x = obj.func;  x();`  doesn't work because there is no `.`,  but `var x = obj.func.bind(x)` will work, because `x` now has `this` bound inside another function.